# Finding length of a character string which is separated by commas in R

Tags: r, string, character, paste

I am newbie to R and i have a scenario to count the length of a every character string separated by comma in R.

I have a following data frame in which it has a column values. I what to find out the length of each cell in this column separated by commas.
I know it has to do with `paste`. but cant get it working

ex: `DF$Values`

`{16337, 21518, 26598, 30461}
{16337, 21518, 26598, 30461,234,836,23}
{123,444,16337, 21518, 26598, 30461}`

I want the results as dataframe with 2 columns. DF$Length should give the length of the column values

`DF$Values, DF$Length`

`{16337, 21518, 26598, 30461}        ,    4
{16337, 21518, 26598, 30461,234,836,23}, 7
{123,444,16337, 21518, 26598, 30461},    6`

Thanks In advance

Comment: Please use `dput(head(DF, 3))` or something like that. You might want to look at `count.fields`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto - I had the same thought, though `count.fields` is rather ugly when the data is already in a data.frame, e.g. `vapply(dat$V1, function(x) count.fields(textConnection(as.character(x)),sep=","), FUN.VALUE=1L)`

Comment: `DF$Length <- lengths(strsplit(DF$Values, ","))` might help

Comment: @AnandaMahto thanks for introducing me new function count.fields. It solved my problem

Comment: @thelatemail, eh? `count.fields` is vectorized, isn't it? `count.fields(textConnection(as.character(dat$V1)), sep = ",")` should do it....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using @akrun's sample data, here's the `count.fields` approach I mentioned in the comments.

```
> count.fields(textConnection(DF$Values), sep = ",")
[1] 4 7 6
```

If they are factors, just use `textConnection(as.character(DF$Values))` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
DF$Length <- sapply(gregexpr(",",DF$Values), length) + 1
```

Comment: `sapply(...,length)` is `lengths(...)` in recent R versions.

Comment: @carlos : also your solution helped me

Answer (score 0):

One solution using data.table is:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(values=c("{16337, 21518, 26598, 30461}", "{16337, 21518, 26598, 30461,234,836,23}", "{123,444,16337, 21518, 26598, 30461}"))
df[, lengthVal:= length(unlist(strsplit(values(.I), split=","))), by=values]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `gsub`

```
nchar(gsub('[^,]', '', DF$Values)) +1L
#[1] 4 7 6
```

Based on the benchmark in the duplicate link, the `gsub` method is faster compared to `count.fields`.  If we need a faster approach

```
library(stringi)
stri_count_fixed(DF$Values, ",") + 1
#[1] 4 7 6
```

#### data

```
DF <- data.frame(Values = c("16337, 21518, 26598, 30461", 
  "16337, 21518, 26598, 30461,234,836,23", 
    "123,444,16337, 21518, 26598, 30461"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```